# How to populate a laravel chart with data from database with apexchart?

Tags: javascript, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-blade, apexcharts

In my controller I have this query :

```
$categories = DB::table('categories')
    ->select('type',DB::raw('COUNT(*) as count_type')) 
    ->groupBy('type')
    ->orderBy('type','desc')
    ->get();
```

When I populate **series** and **labels** with static results everything works fine, but when I try to populate it from database it doesn't work, The whole problem is with **series** and **labels** as shown below in the script :

```
    <script>
            var options = {
here=>        series: [@foreach($categories as $categorie) $categorie->count_type @endforeach],
              chart: {
              width: 380,
              type: 'pie',
            },
and here=>    labels: [@foreach($categories as $categorie) $categorie->type @endforeach],
            responsive: [{
              breakpoint: 480,
              options: {
                chart: {
                  width: 200
                },
                legend: {
                  position: 'bottom'
                }
              }
            }]
            };
            var chart = new ApexCharts(document.querySelector("#chart"), options);
            chart.render();
    </script>
```

So the question is how can I populate this graph from my query result?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it still is an issue for You, but I solved it by creating the chart in the component and loop through the data, via a foreach-loop adding data to the chart.

Livewire Component:

```
    $pieChartModel = (new PieChartModel())
   ->setTitle('Prenumerationer');
   foreach($assets as $asset) {
       // Create a random color
       $color = '#' . str_pad(dechex(mt_rand(0, 0xFFFFFF)), 6, '0', 
       STR_PAD_LEFT);
       if(is_null($asset->assetname)) {
          // AddSlice can't handle null values for label
          $label = 'Empty';
       }
       else {
          $label = $asset->assetname;
       }
       // Convert $asset->assettypes to integer
       $value = intval($asset->assettypes);
       // Add Slice to the PieChart
       $pieChartModel->addSlice($label, $value, $color);
   }

return view('livewire.asset-charts')
    ->with([
        'pieChartModel' => $pieChartModel,
    ]);
```

Livewire Blade:

```
    <div class="flex flex-col sm:flex-row space-y-4 sm:space-y-0 sm:space-x-4">
    <div class="shadow rounded p-4 border bg-white flex-1" style="height: 32rem;">
        <livewire:livewire-pie-chart
            :pie-chart-model="$pieChartModel"
        />
    </div>
</div>
```

Laravel Blade:

```
<div>
  @livewire('asset-charts')
</div>
```

Regards
Marcus